# How to append to PathBuf

Tags: rust, path

Is there an elegant way to append a suffix such as `.bak` to a `Path` and get a new `PathBuf`? Something like:

```
let p = Path::new("foo.c");
let p_bak = /* ? */;
assert_eq!(p_bak, Path::new("foo.c.bak"));
```

With a string, one could use `format!("{}.bak", p)`. With a path, I see no obvious equivalent. `with_extension()` doesn't quite do it, as `p.with_extension("bak")` will create `foo.bak` rather than the desired `foo.c.bak`.

The most "obvious" solution is to define an `append_to_path()` and use `append_to_path(p, ".bak")`:

```
fn append_to_path(p: &Path, s: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let mut p_osstr = p.as_os_str().to_owned();
    p_osstr.push(s);
    p_osstr.into()
}
```

Is there a shorter way of expressing that?

The `tap` crate allows to put it in one streamlined expression, but it still feels rather cryptic:

```
// prior to Rust 1.70:
let p_bak: PathBuf = p.as_os_str().to_owned().tap_mut(|s| s.push(".bak")).into();

// since Rust 1.70:
let p_bak = p.to_owned().tap_mut(|s| s.as_mut_os_string().push(".bak"));
```

Comment: I think that's probably the best way, though I would probably implement it with an extension trait instead.

Comment: @PitaJ Agreed in general, though an extension trait is too much boilerplate if you need this in only one place.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is any shorter way of doing it. However, we can write the function in a way that is slightly more efficient.

```
fn append_to_path(p: PathBuf, s: &str) -> PathBuf {
    let mut p = p.into_os_string();
    p.push(s);
    p.into()
}
```

`into_os_string()` is more efficient than `as_os_str().to_owned()`. `into_os_string()` and `as_os_str()` are both very cheap, but `to_owned()` clones the whole path, which requires a dynamic memory allocation.

However, `into_os_string()` can only be used on `PathBuf`, not on `&Path`, so we need to change the signature accordingly. By taking a `PathBuf` by value, we shift the responsibility for cloning the `PathBuf` to the caller, but it also enables the caller to avoid cloning if it doesn't need to.

We can also make the function more convenient to use by using the `Into` trait:

```
fn append_to_path(p: impl Into<OsString>, s: impl AsRef<OsStr>) -> PathBuf {
    let mut p = p.into();
    p.push(s);
    p.into()
}
```

`&Path` and `PathBuf` implement `Into<OsString>`, so we can pass values of these types straight to the function's first parameter. When a `&Path` is converted into an `OsString`, the `Into` implementation for `&Path` will perform a dynamic memory allocation, but when a `PathBuf` is converted, no memory allocation will occur. For the second parameter, I just used the same trait bounds that [`OsString::push`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ffi/struct.OsString.html#method.push) has for its `s` parameter.

Comment: I guess these optimizations make sense as a general Rust tip, but they fail to address the actual question, which is specifically about a shorter way of expressing this operation (i.e. avoid a utility function to begin with).

Answer (score -2):

```
let p_bak: PathBuf = (p.to_string_lossy().to_string() + ".bak").into();
// or
let p_bak: PathBuf = PathBuf::from(p.to_string_lossy().to_string() + ".bak");
```

Usage of `to_string_lossy` avoids using `to_string` which returns `Option<&str`> but should be only used when we know the string is going to be composed valid unicode characters

Comment: Have you tried either of these solutions? For me both fail to compile with "error[E0369]: cannot add `&str` to `OsString`" - e.g. https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e75e6f53c3c2e34c615220c1f89a9b18

Comment: @user4815162342 Sorry about that, just updated the response after I tested it

Comment: As noted in the answer, these snippets silently corrupt paths with non-UTF-8 characters. If that were acceptable, I'd just use strings in the first place.